# scikit-multiflow graphs not loading/updating

Tags: python

I am trying to get the prediction from the evaluator but I only get a plain graph that is not loading or updating

```
from skmultiflow.data import WaveformGenerator
from skmultiflow.trees import HoeffdingTreeClassifier
from skmultiflow.evaluation import EvaluatePrequential
    
# 1. Create a stream
stream = WaveformGenerator()
    
# 2. Instantiate the HoeffdingTreeClassifier
ht = HoeffdingTreeClassifier()

# 3. Setup the evaluator
evaluator = EvaluatePrequential(show_plot=True,
                                pretrain_size=200,
                                max_samples=20000)
    
# 4. Run evaluation
evaluator.evaluate(stream=stream, model=ht)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this at the beginning of your code:

```
%matplotlib
```